# Enabling touch event on Objects In a UIScrollview

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview

I've a `scrollview` that has a `UIView` on it and on those Views, there's a `UIImageView` on it, three `UILabel` on it, I want to enable user Interaction on it, but wouldn't work. I've enabled `setUserInteraction` for both the `UIView`, `UIScrollView`, `UILabels`, `UIImageView` none is Responding to click actions at all. The layout look like the Image Below....[image: Objects On UIView]

Comment: set setUserInteraction enable for UIScrollView.

Comment: what do you mean no touch events? how are you listening to those events?

Comment: I already did, you're not reading what I wrote above

Comment: have you tried to add a gesture recognisers?

Comment: I'm using **UIGestureRecognizer** to listen to the taps on it @KingBabar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

implement

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

so the gestures of the uiscroll view won't conflict with the subview's recognisers

basically what happens is that the UIScrollView won't pass the events to its subviews because the default of the above method is to return NO

Comment: make sure to set the delegate of the subview's recognisers

Comment: Should I return anything in the function above?

Comment: the simplest solution would be to always return YES

Comment: Not responding, I added the recognizer on everything in the view and the view itself, non is responding to click events

Comment: have you added the controller as the recogniser delegate?

Comment: whether this event is called ?put breakpoint on it and check.

Comment: also make sure that you the delegate of the scrollview

Comment: I was passing UIGestureRecognizer instead of UITapGestureRecognizer

Answer (score 0):

This sounds too easy to be the problem, but I've made the following mistake:  Everything is set just right, but I did not drag out one of the SentEvents like TouchUpInside to an action in the implementation.

[image: SentEvents]

Comment: Mind you, the only thing that's on the Storyboard is the ScrollView, every other thing are done programmatically, and I can't find anything like Sent Events when I click on the scroollview

Answer (score 0):

check this way,
1> first check whether your view controller respond to UIGestureRecognizerDelegate this way

```
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```

2> then in design check you map scrollview property and delegate properly

3> apply this code in viewDidload

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapditected)];
tapGesture.delegate = self;
// prevents the scroll view from swallowing up the touch event of child buttons
tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
[self.scroller addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

4> check you apply this code

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

{
    return YES;
}

5> if all goes wll then  this method should detected

```
-(void)tapditected{
```

}

Comment: I was passing UIGestureRecognizer instead of UITapGestureRecognizer

Comment: UIGestureRecognizer is an abstract class, you're not supposed to add it directly to your view. You should use a concrete subclass that inherits from UIGestureRecognizer, like UITapGestureRecognizer or UIPanGestureRecognizer for example.